# Differece between two ways of using scanf

Tags: c, scanf

What is the difference between these two segments of code:

1

```
scanf("%d%d", p1, p2);
```

2

```
scanf("%d", p1); 
scanf("%d", p2);
```

Comment: Why not read the manual page?

Comment: @Mauren: Just testing code you're unsure of is dangerous, because its easy to get something that appears to work without realizing that there are undefined corner cases involved that could cause failures later.  Reading the documentation is always a much better choice.

Comment: @ChrisDodd I agree, but still I usually ally both choices.

Answer (score 4):

Since you're not checking the return values, there is no difference in the behavior.  If you were checking the return values, the second option potentially gives you a little more detail (two return values to check) for a little more work.  If the input is a single number followed by an EOF, the second will return 1,EOF.  If the input is a single number followed by a non-number, it will return 1,0.  The first option will return 1 in either of the above cases, so you can't tell the difference without another call (if you care).

Answer (score 1):

I am posting this because it will helpful for you to use scanf in different way::

if you input like::

below all input taking in different variable and array

8 5

2 3 1 2 3 2 3 3

0 2

0 1

6 7

3 5

0 7

then how to use scanf

if you want to take input from console as "space separated input" ex:: 1 2 3 4 5 5 6

then you can use scanf() as below

for(i=0; i < no_you_want;i++)

{

// single space before %d in below scanf function

scanf("   %d",&a[i]);

}

Comment: A space before `"%d"` makes no difference.  `"%d"` consumes leading white-space on its own, just like `" "` does.  C11 §7.21.6.2 8 "Input white-space characters (as specified by the isspace function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a [, c, or n specifier."

Comment: i working on hacker-rank and for space separated input from console i am using the same and also getting points on that question and its working fine,why cant you try once.i am refering C99 standard.

Comment: `scanf(" %d",&a[i]);` and `scanf("%d",&a[i]);` work the same.  Both work fine.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to add '&' in your inputs ;-) Like Chris mentioned there is no difference in working unless you handle the return value. I tried to compare the assembly code, of-course there are couple of extra instructions as below.

```
scanf("%d%d", &p1, &p2);

main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16 
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $.LC0, %eax
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rdx
        leaq    -8(%rbp), %rcx
        movq    %rcx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    __isoc99_scanf
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret 
        .cfi_endproc

scanf("%d", &p1); 
scanf("%d", &p2);

main:
.LFB0:
        .cfi_startproc
        pushq   %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_offset 16
        .cfi_offset 6, -16 
        movq    %rsp, %rbp
        .cfi_def_cfa_register 6
        subq    $16, %rsp
        movl    $.LC0, %eax
        leaq    -8(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    %rdx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    __isoc99_scanf
        movl    $.LC0, %eax
        leaq    -4(%rbp), %rdx
        movq    %rdx, %rsi
        movq    %rax, %rdi
        movl    $0, %eax
        call    __isoc99_scanf
        movl    $0, %eax
        leave
        .cfi_def_cfa 7, 8
        ret 
        .cfi_endproc
```

Comment: Sorry not able to format the assembly code properly.:(

Answer (score 0):

An expected difference between `scanf("%d%d", p1, p2);` and `scanf("%d", p1); 
scanf("%d", p2);` occurs when the input text is `"-+2\n"`.

With `scanf("%d%d", p1, p2);`, `scanf()` read `"-+"` and seeing that it is not a valid `int` sequence, ungets the `+` for subsequent IO.  `*p1` and `*p2` remain unchanged.

With `scanf("%d", p1);`, `scanf()` read `"-+"` and seeing that it is not a valid `int` sequence, (`*p1` remains unchanged) ungets the `+` for subsequent IO which is `scanf("%d", p2);` which scans `"+3\n"`, save `3` into `*p2` and ungets the `\n` for subsequent IO.

> C11dr §7.21.6.2 9 footnote about `fscanf()`, which applies to `scanf()`: "fscanf **pushes back at most one input character onto the input stream**. Therefore, some sequences that are acceptable to strtod, strtol, etc., are unacceptable to fscanf.

**But I can not make it differ on my machine.**

My cygwin Kepler gcc unexpectedly pushes back *both* `"-+"` causing both codes to operate the same.  Your mileage may vary.  My gcc appears to not comply with the C spec.